# Accessing an array passed as a name attribute in HTML from PHP?

Tags: php, html, attributes

I have made a simple HTML form from which I want to obtain all the ticked checkboxes' names via PHP. However when I try to do this with the superglobal `$_POST[]` variable nothing is assigned to the corresponding variable. I would like to ask how can easily accomplish this?
Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Questionaire</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Please, enter your information:</p>
City: <input type="text" name="">
Month: <input type="text" name="">
Year: <input type="text" name="">
<p>Please, choose the kinds of weather you experienced from the list below.</p>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="weather[]" id="o1"><label for="o1">Sunshine</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="weather[]" id="o2"><label for="o2">Clouds</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="weather[]" id="o3"><label for="o3">Rain</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="weather[]" id="o4"><label for="o4">Hail</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="weather[]" id="o5"><label for="o5">Sleet</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="weather[]" id="o6"><label for="o6">Snow</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="weather[]" id="o7"><label for="o7">Wind</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="weather[]" id="o8"><label for="o8">Cold</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="weather[]" id="o9"><label for="o9">Heat</label>
<br>
<br>
<button>Go</button>
</body>
</html>
<?php 
$ar[] = $_POST[weather[]];
// I want to threat the $ar variable as an array, but I cannot
print_r($ar);
//. . . . 
 ?>
```

Comment: Isn't it suppose to be `$_POST['weather']` ? `$ar = $_POST['weather']`

Comment: And where are the `form` tags, the `submit` the `value` of the input ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to correct the code as well as add form field value. Here is the short example form.

```
 <form action="" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="weather[]" id="o1" value="Sunshine"><label for="o1">Sunshine</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="weather[]" id="o2" value="Clouds"><label for="o2">Clouds</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="weather[]" id="o3" value="Rain"><label for="o3">Rain</label>

<button>Go</button>
</form>

<?php 
if (isset($_POST['weather'])) {
$ar = $_POST['weather'];

print_r($ar);
}
 ?>
```